# ROS hydro xsens_driver for MTi

Tags: ros, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the xsens_driver (http://wiki.ros.org/xsens_driver ) support hydro? As there is no files under the hydro version.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198085/ros-hydro-xsens_driver-for-mti/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The master branch cannot work directly for ROS hydro version.

But we could install the ros-hydro-gps-common from the Synaptic Package Manager.

And then $git clone https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_xsens_driver.git 
$catkin_make

After that, it should work

To use the xsens_driver, the USB access shall be changed to the administrator

$sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0

Then the xsens_driver could be launched and the imu data could be viewed by the following command.

$roslaunch xsens_driver xsens_driver.launch
$rostopic echo /imu/data

---

Originally posted by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) with karma: 286 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried installing it from debs?

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-xsens-driver
```

Works for me, and appears to install the appropriate driver nodes. I don't have an xsens, so I can't test if the driver actually works or not.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1